# Operation was cancelled before it could be completed

Tags: c#, msmq

I have two private message queues that get the same error, almost at the same time.

```
var msgLog = _msmqLogging.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeoutSeconds));

if (msgLog != null) {
    var objLogEntry = msgLog.Body as LogEntry;

    _dsLog.Create(objLogEntry, _strConnection);
}
```

The exception I get is

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005):  Operation was cancelled before it could be completed.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 action, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
```

This code is running on several other machines, but only occurs on one specific machine. The MessageQueue doesn't seem to work afterwards. The method is called from within a Thread and the exception is caught. That's why I suspect a problem with MSMQ in general on this machine. I'll try to get more information from Event-Log, just wanted to know if someone has encountered this behavior in past.

After analyzing Windows Event Logs I found these error messages immediately before we get our first exception:

```
1 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-1809061258-1204303289-1778214163-1007:
Process 9208 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1809061258-1204303289-1778214163-1007


1 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-2206066462-397448001-1194320622-1113:
Process 1056 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\svchost.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-2206066462-397448001-1194320622-1113\Printers\DevModePerUser
```

Comment: 0x80004005 is not an MSMQ error code so this is external to MSMQ. 
What timeout are you using? How quickly do you see the exception?

Comment: My timeout is 20 seconds, I see it probably once in a week

Comment: I found this `MQ_ERROR_OPERATION_CANCELLED (0xC00E0008)

The operation was canceled before it could be completed. For example, the queue handle was closed by another thread while waiting for a message.` So I start looking for something that is closing my handle

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: I got the Windows Event Logs these days and found some interesting messages 2 seconds before the MessageQueuing Exception appears in our application. `Erlang machine volountarily stopped. The service is not restarted as OnFail is set to ignore.` and more important I think `1 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-1809061258-1204303289-1778214163-1007:
Process 9208 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1809061258-1204303289-1778214163-1007
`